# Getting wrong date while using new Date() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm storing the ISO datetime value in database and when is use the `new Date()` method it is showing wrong date.

When I use `new Date().toISOString()` output is `2021-05-05T13:33:35.673Z` and when is use `new Date(event.date).toISOString()` output is `2021-05-05T18:47:00.000Z`.

But when I try `new Date().getDate()` the output is `5`, but for `new Date(event.date).getDate()` the output is `6`. Why is it `6` instead of `5`?

Comment: what is the value of event.date

Comment: event.date value is `2021-05-05T18:47:00.000Z`

Comment: So you're getting the correct output. What were you expecting instead, and why?

Comment: im getting wrong output for date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here is that `getDate` uses your **local** timezone, but `toISOString` shows you the information in UTC.

If you want the same day value that's in the ISO string (which is in UTC), use `getUTCDate`:

```js
console.log(new Date("2021-05-05T18:47:00.000Z").getUTCDate());
```

Comment: getting answer 3 ;(

Comment: @IshanJoshi - Not with the code above and the input you've described you won't. I'm guessing you accidentally used `getUTCDay` (day of week), not `getUTCDate` (day of month). (`getUTCDay` will indeed give you 3, because the 5th is Wednesday and it's 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...)

Comment: ya got it thank you. So dumb mistake. it took me 30 min

Comment: I'm getting the wrong date. It's November 25th 2022 at the time I'm writing this and when I run your codes, it returns November 5th 2022. I'm having the same issue in my program atm.

Comment: @Grogu - It sounds like your string isn't quite in the format above. If it were, the results would be reliable. [The format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format) is year, month, day, the letter T, hour, minutes, seconds, a `.`, milliseconds, and the letter `Z` for UTC. Everything is two digits except year (four) and milliseconds (three).